# How to add characters to an existing character array in Fortran?

Tags: string, fortran

I've seen alot about how to combine two strings into one new string in Fortran.  But what if I have a string already, but want to add new characters to it?  I thought the operation

```
old_str = old_str//new_str
```

would do it, assuming `old_str` has enough space to hold `new_str`.  But `old_str` doesn't change:

```
program teststr

character(len=8) :: old_str, new_str

old_str="foo"
new_str="bar"
old_str=old_str//new_str

print *, old_str

end program
```

I compile and run and get "foo" for output.

Comment: There's no character array in this question. But you probably need to consider `trim()` and/or deferred length characters.

Comment: `old_str//new_str` is a length-16 expression, and only the first 8 characters are assigned to the left-hand side, and that's `"foo     "` with five trailing spaces.